# how to get item values from QListView in pyqt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside

After connecting to my DB i try to get all the items value from QListView
but it doesn't have text() method or any thing else i tried to use the model.data() but it returns the following error:

> File "c:\Users\inter\Desktop\neosun\main copy 9.py", line 88, in
> addToPlaylist
> item = model.data(index, 1, Qt.DisplayRole) TypeError: data(self, QModelIndex, role: int = Qt.DisplayRole): argument 1 has unexpected
> type 'int'

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(900,180,800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Display")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('favicon.png'))
        self.model = QSqlQueryModel()
        self.model.setQuery("SELECT path FROM files")
        
        self.listview = QListView()
        self.listview.setModel(self.model)
        self.listview.setModelColumn(1)    
        self.getData()

    
    def getData(self):
        model = self.listview.model()
        for index in range(model.rowCount()):
            # item = model.data(index)
            item = model.data(index, 1, Qt.DisplayRole)
            print(item)
```

Comment: Hey there, the error has nothing to do with the question itself. The error tells you that your argument is an integer, while it shouldn't be or isn't correct. So please clarify what your question is. Is it about solving the error or the question how to get an item from a specific index in the [QListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt uses the [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) class to locate data within any model, so you cannot just use integers to access them, but [`model.index(row, column, parent=None)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) must be used instead (the optional parent argument is for multidimensional models, like tree models).

```
    def getData(self):
        model = self.listview.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            index = model.index(row, 1)
            item = model.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
            print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works , only in the index the column is 0 because i set model column to 1

Comment: You have set the model column that is *shown in the view*, but the model structure doesn't change. In your question you were trying to get the data from the second column (1), so I just used that value based on your code.